# Removing SharePoint Online Site's Left Tool Bar

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, administration, sharepoint-app-bar

I have a SharePoint Online site that was created using the 'Communication site' template.

I want to remove the left toolbar as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

I couldn't locate any option under 'Site settings' to remove the left toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

This left tool bar in SharePoint is called as **SharePoint app bar**. There is no option under 'Site settings' to remove the SharePoint app bar as this is tenant level setting.

**How to disable the SharePoint app bar?**:

You cannot disable the SharePoint app bar permanently. However, you can temporarily disable the SharePoint app bar in your tenant using PowerShell until **March 31, 2022** (Previously October 31, 2021).

To temporarily disable the SharePoint app bar:

1. Download the latest version of [SharePoint Online PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online).
2. Then, run the following command with administrator privileges:

```
Set-SPOTemporarilyDisableAppBar $true
```

**Source**: [Introducing a SharePoint app bar that features global navigation](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/02/24/introducing-a-sharepoint-app-bar-that-features-global-navigation/)

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if my reply helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

There are some notes when you temporarily disable the SharePoint app bar:

- It can **take up to an hour** for the app bar to be removed on a tenant
  where the app bar is already showing up.
- Running the command without the $false or $true value will cause it
  to fail.
- You must be using **the latest version** of PowerShell.
- If you are using previous versions, uninstall the previous version
  and then install the most up to date version. Previous versions of
  PowerShell can't coexist with the most up-to-date version of
  PowerShell.

Here is the official link about new SharePoint app bar for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-app-bar#temporarily-disable-the-sharepoint-app-bar